# Adding a curve to a histogram?

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I'd like to add a curve with it's x and y coordinates already defined to a histogram. Consider the histogram below:

```
set.seed(38593)
expRandom <- rexp(10000)
x <- seq(from = 0.05, to = 10, by = 0.001)
y <- exp(-x)
### Now I'd like to first draw my histogram and then 
### add my plot(x,y) to my existing histogram:
hist(expRandom, freq = FALSE)

### ?? How to add my plot(x,y) to my histogram above?
```

Thanks,

Comment: That has been asked and answered numerous times here and elsewhere. Did you try a search?

Comment: Oh oh... I did a quick search and I didn't find. Should I delete the post?

Comment: That is not the purpose of SO (in my opinion)

Comment: But I thought that it works like a forum that people can ask their questions...Am I misunderstood? I apologize anyways.

Comment: Searched for `[r] curve histogram`, found these on the first page of results: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497539/fitting-a-density-curve-to-a-histogram-in-r  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080139/histogram-and-pdf-in-the-same-graph http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872525/r-plot-histogram-and-density-function-curve-on-one-chart http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046664/how-to-use-the-function-curve-in-r-to-graph-a-normal-curve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sett `freq = FALSE` to plot the densities not frequencies in the histogram and use `points` (or `lines`) to add your data.

```
hist(expRandom, freq = FALSE)
points(x,y)
```

You could also avoid having to precaclulate the  `y` values by using `curve` to add a curve

```
hist(expRandom, freq = FALSE)
curve(dexp, from = 0, to  = 10, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your answer @mnel.